# Switch widget always returning to off position

Tags: flutter

I am working on a form where I need to use a switch widget.

Here you have the code for it:

```
bool isSwitched31 = false;
../
Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'nuevopaciente31'.tr().toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                    Spacer(),
                    Switch(
                      value: isSwitched31,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          isSwitched31 = value;
                          print(isSwitched31);
                        });
                      },
                      activeTrackColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
                      activeColor: Colors.green,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

[image]

When sliding the switch, the print output tells that the swich is on, but it returns always to off position.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you can add full code? I need more information like: where are declarate the isSwitched31 variable.

Comment: @FelipeVergara, it is declared inside the Widget build(BuildContext context),

Comment: is `bool isSwitched31 = false;` inside `build()`? If so move it outside to make it a class member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare the variable inside the build method, when the widget is rebuilt 'isSwitched31' will be false again. To fix this you have to declare 'isSwitched31' before the build method